# DOM diff algorithm with HTML streaming?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, diff, depth-first-search

Does anybody know if the DOM diff algorithm can be applied in [Depth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) search (DFS) instead of [Breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) search (BFS)? I've been trying for days to get the DOM diff algorithm to work with streaming HTML, but I'm having troubles (different approach than React). Does anyone know of an open-source example?

For now I did this helper to get the Nodes from streaming:

```
const decoder = new TextDecoder();

export default async function* parseHTMLStream(
  streamReader: ReadableStreamDefaultReader<Uint8Array>,
  doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(),
  lastChunkNode: Node | null = null,
): AsyncGenerator<Node> {
  const { done, value } = await streamReader.read();

  if (done) return;

  doc.write(decoder.decode(value));

  let lastNode = lastChunkNode
    ? getNextNode(lastChunkNode)
    : doc.documentElement;

  for (let node = lastNode; node; node = getNextNode(node)) {
    if (node) lastNode = node;
    yield node;
  }

  yield* await parseHTMLStream(streamReader, doc, lastNode ?? lastChunkNode);
}

/**
 * Get the next node in the tree.
 * It uses depth-first search in order to work with the streamed HTML.
 */
function getNextNode(node: Node | null, deeperDone?: Boolean): Node | null {
  if (!node) return null;
  if (node.childNodes.length && !deeperDone) return node.firstChild;
  return node.nextSibling ?? getNextNode(node.parentNode, true);
}
```

Then I can use the stream nodes directly with:

```
const reader = res.body.getReader();

for await (const node of parseHTMLStream(reader)) {
  console.log(node);
}
```

But then you lose context of whether it was child, slibing and which real dom it has to compare with without creating bugs by updating only the DOM nodes that have changed. I have come to think that if React and all the examples are in Breadth-first that it is not that you can't implement the DOM diff algorithm with Depth-first. Is this so? And if not, does anyone have an example of how it would be implemented?

Comment: What are you referring to by "*the DOM diff algorithm*"?

Comment: update the real DOM only affecting the parts that chance it, similar than the virtual dom of react but with the real dom. There are a lot of implementations: set-dom, morphdom, nanomorph... But all these librararies are working without streaming. What I want is to use this algorithm with HTML streaming because I'm implementing a RPC (remote procedure call).

Comment: I've looked at the packages you mentioned and they appear to be using a simple recursive depth-first traversal. What makes you think they do BFS?

Comment: From what I can understand, these algorithms first visit the children, but before entering the children of the children, they first visit all the child sibling elements of the initial layer. That's why it makes me think they are BFS.

Comment: No. At least [this algorithm](https://github.com/DylanPiercey/set-dom/blob/master/src/index.js#L139) doesn't. There is no queue of unprocessed nodes anywhere, as would be typical for BFS. The `setNode` calls are strictly a depth-first traversal.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks! Do you think it is possible to make it work with streaming? I have tried but the [isEqualNode](https://github.com/DylanPiercey/set-dom/blob/846b9337246e3b06e6b41b228beeea21e66d0b03/src/index.js#L63) for example is not viable because it looks at everything inside when chunks may not have arrived yet.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Sure, for an incomplete chunk the nodes will never be considered equal, but that just means you have to go down to apply changes as far as you can, that's by design.